# How do I modify the OnGetItem method generated by WCF Rest Starter Kit 2?

Tags: wcf, rest

I have created a Rest collection WCF Service using the starter kit.
Everything is fine except I need to modify the `OnGetItem(string id)` to accept an additional parameter such that the URI becomes

http://localhost/service.svc/1/5

where 1 = department id 
and 5 = employee id

I can see the `ICollectionService<ITem>` within the abstract class collection service base
`protected abstract TItem OnGetItem(string id);` but I am not allowed to modify it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make such a simple addition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already found your answer on [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1433999.aspx).